# Java SWT get bounds of custom element in TreeView

Tags: java, tree, swt, selection, treeviewer

I´ve created a `TreeView` with a `ContentProvider` and custom tree elements.
I also have a `ISelectionChangedListener` added to the `TreeView`.

I want to add an `MouseListener`, do detect if an element of the tree is right-clicked and show a popup menu.
If the white area around the tree is clicked, i don´t want to display the popup menu. 
The menu is added via `Extensions` in the plugin.xml.

How can I now evaluate if a `tree` element is right-clicked, so I can show the popup menu (maybe with visibleWhen in the plugin.xml) ?
I also want to clear the selection, if the right-click is detected in the white area of the `TreeView`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i did not realized that i can still use `tree.getItem(...)`.
So here is my full `MouseListener`:

```
treeOPCUA.addMouseListener(new MouseListener()
{
    @Override
    public void mouseUp(MouseEvent e)
    {
        if(e.button == 3 && rightMouseClicked == true)
            rightMouseClicked = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseDown(MouseEvent e)
    {
        if(e.button == 3 && rightMouseClicked == false)
            rightMouseClicked = true;
        if(treeOPCUA.getItem(new Point(e.x, e.y)) == null)
            viewer.setSelection(null);
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseDoubleClick(MouseEvent e)
    {
        viewer.setExpandedState(e.getSource(), true);
    }
});
```

With the `boolean` variable "`rightMouseClicked`" I detect in my `ISelectionChangedListener` if the right mouse is clicked:

```
if(event.getSelection() instanceof IStructuredSelection && !rightMouseClicked)
```

I hope this answer helps anyone.